Vector bundle construction theorem
Let $M$ be a k-dimensional smooth manifold, and let $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ be an open cover of $M$. Further, for any $\alpha, \beta \in I$, let there be given smooth maps $\varphi_{\alpha\beta}:U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\to \text{GL}(k,\mathbb{R})$, and let these maps satisfy the cocycle condition for any $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in I$ with non-empty intersections:
$$
\varphi_{\alpha\gamma}(p)= \varphi_{\alpha\beta}(p)\cdot \varphi_{\beta\gamma}(p) \ \ \forall p\in U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\cap U_\gamma
$$
Then we can construct a (unique up to isomorphism) rank k vector bundle over $M$ such that the transition functions on $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$ are given by $\varphi_{\alpha\beta}$. The first is to define an equivalence relation on the set
$$
\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}\{\alpha\}\times U_\alpha\times \mathbb{R}^k
$$
as $(\alpha,p,v)\sim(\beta,q,u):\Leftrightarrow p=q\  \text{and}\ v=\varphi_{\alpha\beta}(p)w$. I have checked that this is an equivalence relation. The next step is defining the following:
$$
\pi: E:=\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}\{\alpha\}\times U_\alpha\times \mathbb{R}^k/\sim\ \longrightarrow M,\ [(\alpha,p,v)]\mapsto p
$$
and give $E$ the quotient topology. But now I'm stucked here:

How to show that $E$ is a smooth manifold? I see somewhere that if $U\subseteq U_\alpha$ is the domain of a chart of M $h:U\to V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$, then $V\times \mathbb{R}^k\to E,(y,v)\mapsto [(\alpha,h^{-1}(y),v)] (h^{-1}y\in U_\alpha)$ is a local trivialization of $\pi^{-1}(U)$. I'm not sure whether it is right, because it seems to be dependent on $\alpha\in I$, and despite the dependence on $\alpha$,I also don't know how can it be a parametrization.
Suppose $E$ is already a smooth manifold, then how to prove it is a vector bundle? For example the simplest thing to verify is $\pi^{-1}(b)$ has the structure of vector space. But for fixed $b$, $\pi^{-1}(b)=\{[(\alpha,b,v)]\mid \alpha\in I,v\in\mathbb{R}^K\}$. But how can I get rid of the influence of $I$ so that $\pi^{-1}(b)\cong \mathbb{R}^k$? And what about local trivializations?

Any help of some points or remarks are appreciated.

Question 1
$E = \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} {\alpha} × U_{\alpha} × \Bbb R^{n} / \text{equivalence-relation} =: \rho$.
(The cup is disjoint union.)

For Hausdorffness, take two elements first. Then, by the Hausdorffness of $M$, if $\pi(x) ≠ \pi(x')$, they are contained in each neighborhoods $U$ and $U'$. So, $x$ and $x'$ are contained in $\pi^{-1}(U)$ or $\pi^{-1}(U')$. The disjointness of two inverse images can be easily seen by the surjectivity of $\pi$. (These do not have to be coordinate neighbourhoods.)
If images of two elements are equal, you can take a neighborhood $U$ of two equal elements. Since the image of the continuous surjective map $\phi$: $\pi^{-1}(U) \to U × \Bbb R^{n}$ is Hausdorff, you can get disjointness of the neighborhood of images of two elements. If we denote them to $V$ and $V'$, the inverse images of them by the surjective continuous map, you can get they are disjoint, so $x$ and $x'$ are in the two disjoint inverse images of continuous surjective map $\phi$.

And to prove second countability, take a $\mathcal B$ to a countable base for $M$. Then for each elements $U$ of base, take a countable base for $\phi^{-1}(U)$.
Question 2
A vector bundle of dimension n is a triple $(E,M,π)$
consisting of a pair of manifolds E and M connected by a smooth surjective
map $π\colon E → M$ satisfying the following conditions.

For each $x ∈ M$, the inverse image $E_x = π^{−1}(x)$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb R$,
For each $x ∈ M$, there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and a diffeomorphism
$φ\colon U × \Bbb R^n → π^{−1}(U)$ such that (i) the following diagram commutes


where $p_1$ is the projection onto the first factor, (ii) for each y ∈ U, the map $φ_y\colon \Bbb R^n → π^{−1}(y)$, defined by $φ_y (v) = φ(y, v)$, is a linear isomorphism.
Note that locally $π$ is the composition of a diffeomorphism $φ^{−1}$ followed
by a submersion $p_1$, therefore $π$ is a submersion. You can prove that by this definition.

Implicit in the above definition of vector bundle is an important role of the
general linear group $GL(n, R)$, which appears in a transition law (the equation
(1)) between VB-charts. This may be described in the following way.
The definition of a vector bundle $π\colon E → M$ guarantees the existence of
a trivialising covering $U_{ii} ∈ Λ$ of $M$ ($Λ$ = index set) and the VB-charts $φ_i\colon U_i × \Bbb R^n → π^{−1}(U_i)$ satisfying VB2. Then, for any $i, j ∈ Λ$ with $U_i ∩ U_j = ∅$, the diffeomorphism $φ^{−1}_j ◦ φ_i\colon (U_i ∩ U_j ) × \Bbb R^n → (U_i ∩ U_j) × \Bbb R^n$
must be of the form
(1) $φ^{−1}_j ◦ φ_i(x, v) = (x, g_{ji}(x)v)$
for a unique smooth map $g_{ji}$ : $U_i ∩ U_j$ $→$ $GL(n, R)$. In fact, if
$φ_{ix} \colon \Bbb R^n → π^{−1}(x)$
is the map $φ_{ix}(v) = φ_i(x, v)$, then
$g_{ji}(x) = φ^{−1}_{jx} \circ \phi_{ix}$
is a linear isomorphism $\Bbb R^n → \Bbb R^n$. The family of maps ${g_{ji}}$ is called a cocycle. They satisfy the following condition, called the cocycle condition,
(2) $g_{kj} (x) · g_{ji}(x) = g_{ki}(x)$, $x ∈ U_i ∩ U_j ∩ U_k$.
Putting $i = j = k$, and then $k = i$ in this condition, we get
$g_{ii}(x) = id$, for all $x ∈ U_i$, and $g_{ij} (x) = (g_{ji}(x))^{−1}$ for all $x ∈ U_i ∩ U_j$ .
A more general definition of a vector bundle replaces the group $GL(n, R)$ by
a subgroup G of it, and includes the transition law (1) as a third condition VB3,
where the $g_{ji}$ are now maps from $U_i∩U_j$ into $G$ satisfying the cocycle condition
(2). It is then called a vector bundle with structure group $G$ (Definition of vector bundle ). If G is the trivial group {1}, then it follows from VB2 that $E$ is the
product bundle $M × \Bbb R^n$.

• more detailed additional answer: Take each neighborhoods of $x$ and $x'$ to $V$ and $V'$. Then the continuity and surjectivity of $\phi$, and the fact that $x$ and $x'$ are in $\phi^{-1}(V)$, and $\phi^{-1}(V')$, the two inverse images are disjoint, so you can get Hausdorffness of 2nd case of choice about $x$ and $x'$.
And, to get rid of the influence of $I$ for $\pi^{-1}(b)$, we can take local trivialization of it. From the fact like I said in a comment, local trivialization of $\pi^{-1}(b)$ is independent to $I$, because the local trivialization captures the inherent vector space structure of the fiber bundle, which is independent of how we parametrize the base space. And take transition function that $\psi_{\alpha\beta}$, then we just have to consider only one case that $w$ is the image of transition function over $b$ sent by every $v \in \Bbb R^k$, then by the fact that local trivialization of $\pi^{-1}(b)$ is independent of $I$, $\pi^{-1}(b)$ is local trivializations of a fiber bundle are independent of the choice of transition functions. This is because local trivializations focus on a small neighborhood within the base space, and different choices of transition functions only affect how different neighborhoods are glued together. As long as the consistency conditions are met for the chosen transition functions, the local properties of the fiber bundle captured by a trivialization will remain the same.
So, it is independent to influence of all indexes $I$. So, by independence of transition function, it is independent for changing charts. So, the set with any $U_{\alpha}$ is independent for index. Then, we can show that $\pi^{-1}(b)$ is bijective to $\Bbb R^k$ independent for indexes. So, it answers your 2nd question.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Thanks to @snailman I organise the complete and readable proof of the theorem with hopefully all one need to show.
First, we construct the bundle and then prove its uniqueness. The construction is as follows. First, we verify two basic properties guaranteed by the cocycle condition. Let $p \in U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \cap U_\gamma$ (non-empty intersection). The cocycle condition indicates $\varphi_{\alpha\gamma}(p) = \varphi_{\alpha\beta}(p) \cdot \varphi_{\beta\gamma}(p)$. Now, setting $\gamma = \beta$, we have $\varphi_{\alpha\beta}(p) = \varphi_{\alpha\beta}(p) \cdot \varphi_{\beta\beta}(p)$, implying $\varphi_{\beta\beta}(p) = \text{id}$, i.e., the transition function $\varphi_{\eta\eta}(p)$ on any open set $\eta \in I$ is the identity map. Setting $\gamma = \alpha$, we get $\varphi_{\alpha\alpha}(p) = \varphi_{\alpha\beta}(p) \cdot \varphi_{\beta\alpha}(p)$, and since $\varphi_{\alpha\alpha}(p) = \text{id}$, we have $\varphi_{\alpha\beta}(p) = [\varphi_{\beta\alpha}(p)]^{-1}$, i.e., the transition functions $\varphi_{\alpha\beta}(p)$ and $\varphi_{\beta\alpha}(p)$ are inverses of each other on any intersecting open sets. Now we define a relation on the set $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} \{\alpha\} \times U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^k$
$$
(\alpha, p, v) \sim (\beta, q, w) :\Leftrightarrow p = q \text{ and } v = \varphi_{\alpha\beta}(p) w.
$$
We verify that this is an equivalence relation:

Reflexivity: For any $(\alpha, p, v) \in \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} \{\alpha\} \times U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^k$, $p = p$, and since $\varphi_{\alpha\alpha}(p) = \text{id}$, $v = \text{id} \cdot v = \varphi_{\alpha\alpha}(p) v$, so $(\alpha, p, v) \sim (\alpha, p, v)$.
Symmetry: Suppose $(\alpha, p, v) \sim (\beta, q, w)$. Then $p = q$, and $v = \varphi_{\alpha\beta}(p) w$. Since $[\varphi_{\beta\alpha}(p)]^{-1} = \varphi_{\alpha\beta}(p)$, $w = \varphi_{\beta\alpha}(p) v$, thus $(\beta, q, w) \sim (\alpha, p, v)$.
Transitivity: Suppose $(\alpha, p, v) \sim (\beta, q, w)$ and $(\beta, q, w) \sim (\gamma, r, u)$. Then $p = q = r$, and $v = \varphi_{\alpha\beta}(p) w$, $w = \varphi_{\beta\gamma}(p) u$. Hence $v = \varphi_{\alpha\beta}(p) \varphi_{\beta\gamma}(p) u = \varphi_{\alpha\gamma}(p) u$ (cocycle condition), thus $(\alpha, p, v) \sim (\gamma, r, u)$.

Therefore, $\sim$ defines an equivalence relation. Define the set of equivalence classes as
$$
E := \bigcup_{\alpha} \{\alpha\} \times U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^k / \sim
$$
Then define $\pi: E \to B, [(\alpha, p, v)] \mapsto p$. Next, we prove that $(E, \pi, B)$ is a vector bundle over $M$. For this, we first prove that $E$ is a smooth manifold. First, we endow $\cup_\alpha \{\alpha\} \times U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^k \subseteq I \times M \times \mathbb{R}^k$ with the subspace topology (where $I$ uses the discrete topology), and then endow $E$ with the quotient topology. Now we first prove its topological properties, i.e., $E$ is Hausdorff and second countable. First, recall that the quotient topology is defined as $U \subseteq E$ is open $\Leftrightarrow \pi_\sim^{-1}(U)$ is open (where $\pi_\sim$ is the projection of the quotient space).

Hausdorff: $\forall x, x' \in E$. We need to prove that there exist open sets $U, U'$ in $E$, such that $x \in U, x' \in U', U \cap U' = \emptyset$. We consider two cases. In the first case, $\pi(x) \ne \pi(x')$. Since $B$ is Hausdorff as a smooth manifold, there exist open sets $U, U'$ in $B$ such that $\pi(x) \in U, \pi(x') \in U', U \cap U' = \emptyset$. Therefore, $x \in \pi^{-1}(U), x' \in \pi^{-1}(U'), \pi^{-1}(U) \cap \pi^{-1}(U') = \emptyset$. For $\pi^{-1}(U)$, we have
$$
\pi^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_{\substack{\alpha \in I \\ U_\alpha \cap U \ne \emptyset}} \{\alpha\} \times (U_\alpha \cap U) \times \mathbb{R}^n / \sim \overset{\pi_\sim^{-1}}{\rightarrow} \bigcup_{\substack{\alpha \in I \\ U_\alpha \cap U \ne \emptyset}} \{\alpha\} \times \underbrace{(U_\alpha \cap U)}_{\text{open set in } M \text{, still open}} \times \underbrace{\mathbb{R}^n}_{\text{open}} \subseteq I \times M \times \mathbb{R}^n
$$
Therefore, $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open. Similarly, $\pi^{-1}(U')$ is also open. So in this case, it is Hausdorff. In the second case, $\pi(x) = \pi(x')$. At this point, we know from the first case that there is an open set $U \subseteq M$ such that $x, x' \in \pi^{-1}(U)$. Let $x = [(\alpha, p, v)]$, then it must be that $x' = [(\alpha', p, v')]$. Case 1, if $v = v'$, then $\alpha \ne \alpha'$. Consider $(\alpha, p, v), (\alpha', p, v) \in I \times U \times \mathbb{R}^n$. Since $I, U (\subseteq B), \mathbb{R}^n$ are all Hausdorff, their product is also Hausdorff. Therefore, there exist open sets $V, V'$ in $I \times U \times \mathbb{R}^n$ (actually in $I \times (U_\alpha \cup U_{\alpha'}) \times \mathbb{R}^n$) such that $(\alpha, p, v) \in V, (\alpha', p, v') \in V'$ and $V \cap V' = \emptyset$. Then consider $\pi_\sim(V), \pi_\sim(V') \subseteq E$. Thus $[(\alpha, p, v)] \in \pi_\sim(V), [(\alpha', p, v)] \in \pi_\sim(V')$, and these two sets are open by the definition of the quotient topology, with $\pi_\sim(V) \cap \pi_\sim(V') = \emptyset$ (because $V \cap V' = \emptyset$). So in this case, Hausdorff holds. Case 2, if $v \ne v'$. Since $v \ne v' \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is Hausdorff, there exist open sets $V, V' \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $v \in V, v' \in V'$ and $V \cap V' = \emptyset$. Therefore, $(\alpha, p, v) \in \{\alpha\} \times U \times V, (\alpha', p, v') \in \{\alpha'\} \times U \times V' \subseteq I \times U \times \mathbb{R}^n$ are all open sets. Because $V \cap V' = \emptyset$, $(\{\alpha\} \times U \times V) \cap (\{\alpha\} \times U \times V') = \emptyset$. Hence, $[(\alpha, p, v)] \in \pi_\sim(\{\alpha\} \times U \times V)$ and $[(\alpha', p, v')] \in \pi_\sim(\{\alpha\} \times U \times V')$. By the definition of the quotient topology, these two sets are open, and their intersection is empty. So in this case, Hausdorff also holds.
Second countable: Since $B$ as a smooth manifold is second countable, let $\mathcal{B} = \{B_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be a countable basis of $B$. Then $\cup_{\alpha \in I} \{\alpha\} \times U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^n$ is also second countable, because $\cup_{\alpha \in I} \{\alpha\} \times \mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ (where $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ is a countable topological basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$) is a countable topological basis of $\cup_{\alpha \in I} \{\alpha\} \times U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^n$, and hence it is second countable. And $\{\pi_\sim(\{\alpha\} \times U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^n)\}_{\alpha \in I}$ is an open cover of $E$, so $\{\pi_\sim(\{\alpha\} \times \mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n})\}_{\alpha \in I}$ forms a countable topological basis of $E$, making $E$ second countable.

The next task is to equip $E$ with a smooth structure. Let $h_\alpha: U \to V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be the local coordinate chart of $B$ at some point $p \in U$, where $U \subseteq U_\alpha$ (if the coordinate domain of the atlas of $B$ is larger than $U_\alpha$, we restrict it to a subset of $U_\alpha$). Consider the map $\tilde h_\alpha: V \times \mathbb{R}^n \to E, (y, v) \mapsto [(\alpha, h^{-1}(y), v)]$. Obviously, this is an injection: Take any $(y, v), (y', v')$ such that $[(\alpha, h^{-1}(y), v)] = [(\alpha, h^{-1}(y'), v')]$. Then, by the definition of the equivalence relation, we know $v' = \psi_{\alpha\alpha}(h^{-1}(y))(v) = id \cdot v = v$, i.e., $v' = v$. Also, by the definition of the equivalence relation, we know $h^{-1}(y) = h^{-1}(y')$. Since $h$ is a diffeomorphism, we have $y = y'$, and thus $(y, v) = (y', v')$. This shows that the map is an injection. Since $\tilde h_\alpha = \pi_\sim \circ (\alpha, h^{-1}, id)$, and all four maps are continuous, $\tilde h_\alpha$ is also continuous. Therefore, the restriction $\tilde h_\alpha \big|_{V \times \mathbb{R}^n}: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \supseteq V \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \tilde h_\alpha(V \times \mathbb{R}^n) \subseteq E$ is a homeomorphism, and thus a local parameterization at the point $[(\alpha, p, v)](\forall v \in \mathbb{R}^n)$ in $U_\alpha$, whose inverse is the local coordinate chart. Let any other local coordinate chart of $B$ be $h'_\beta: U' \to V' \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $\tilde h_\beta' \big|_{V' \times \mathbb{R}^n}(V' \times \mathbb{R}^n) \cap \tilde h_\alpha \big|_{V \times \mathbb{R}^n}(V \times \mathbb{R}^n) \ne \emptyset$. Then on the intersection of these two local coordinate charts in $E$, $\tilde h_\alpha(V \times \mathbb{R}^n) \cap \tilde h_\beta'(V' \times \mathbb{R}^n)$, the map $\tilde h_\alpha \big|_{V \times \mathbb{R}^n}^{-1} \circ \tilde h_\beta' \big|_{V' \times \mathbb{R}^n}$ is given by $(y, v) \mapsto [(\alpha, h_\beta'^{-1}(y)), v] \mapsto (h_\alpha \circ h_\beta'^{-1}(y), v) = (h_\alpha \circ h_\beta'^{-1}, id)(y, v)$. Obviously, since $h_\alpha$ and $h_\beta'$ are both diffeomorphisms, this map is smooth. Therefore, by combining all such $h_\alpha$ in $U_\alpha$, and then combining all $\alpha \in I$, we obtain the smooth atlas of $E$. In conclusion, $E$ is a smooth manifold.
Next, we prove that $\pi: E \to B$ is a rank $n$ vector bundle. First, we show that for a fixed $b \in B$, $\pi^{-1}(b)$ has the structure of an $n$-dimensional vector space. We have
$$
\pi^{-1}(b) = \{[(\alpha, b, v)] \mid \alpha \in I, v \in \mathbb{R}^n\} = \{[(\alpha, b, v)] \mid \alpha \text{ fixed such that } b \in U_\alpha, v \in \mathbb{R}^n\}
$$
We prove the second equality. For any $[(\beta, b, v)]$, by the definition of the equivalence relation, we know $[(\beta, b, v)] = [(\alpha, b, \psi_{\alpha\beta} v)] \subseteq \text{RHS}$. The inclusion in the other direction is obvious. Thus, we only need to define addition and scalar multiplication on $\{[(\alpha, b, v)]\}$ (where $\alpha, b$ are fixed): $[(\alpha, b, v)] + [(\alpha, b, w)] := [(\alpha, b, v + w)]$, $\lambda \cdot [(\alpha, b, v)] := [(\alpha, b, \lambda v)]$. In our rewrite of the set $\pi^{-1}(b)$, we have fixed $\alpha$ and $b$, so the choice of representative is unique in the rewritten form. Hence, addition and scalar multiplication are clearly well-defined, and it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e., it is an $n$-dimensional vector space.
Secondly, we need to find local trivializations. Still fixing $p \in U_\alpha \subseteq B$, define
$$
\phi_\alpha: U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^n \to I \times U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^n / \sim = \pi^{-1}(U_\alpha), (p, v) \mapsto [(\alpha, p, v)]
$$
Obviously, $\phi_\alpha$ is an injection. It is also a surjection because for any $[(\beta, p, v)] \in \pi^{-1}(U)$, we have $\phi_\alpha(p, \psi_{\beta\alpha} v) = [(\alpha, p, \psi_{\beta\alpha} v)] = [(\beta, p, v)]$, so it is a bijection. Therefore, it has an inverse $\Phi_\alpha := \phi_\alpha^{-1}: \pi^{-1}(U) \to U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^n$, and $\Phi_\alpha = \pi_{23} \circ \pi_\sim^{-1}$ (where $\pi_{23}: (\alpha, p, v) \mapsto (p, v)$), hence $\Phi_\alpha$ is also continuous. Therefore, $\Phi_\alpha$ is a local trivialization. We have $\Phi_\alpha \big|_{\pi^{-1}(b)}: \pi^{-1}(b) \to \{b\} \times \mathbb{R}^n, [(\alpha, b, v)] \mapsto (b, v)$, which is clearly an isomorphism of vector spaces. In conclusion, we have proven that $\pi: E \to B$ is a vector bundle. Since $[(\beta, p, v)] = [(\alpha, p, \psi_{\alpha\beta}(p) v)]$, on $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \ne \emptyset$ we have
$$
\Phi_\alpha \circ \Phi_\beta^{-1}(p, v) = \Phi_\alpha [(\beta, p, v)] = \Phi_\alpha [(\alpha, p, \psi_{\alpha\beta}(p) v)] = (p, \psi_{\alpha\beta}(p) v)
$$
That is, the transition function of the vector bundle $\pi: E \to B$ on $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$ is $\psi_{\alpha\beta}$.
Finally, we need to prove uniqueness. Suppose $\pi: E \to B$ is the bundle constructed as above, and suppose $\pi': E' \to B$ is another bundle that can be locally trivialized on $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$ and has the same transition functions. We define a map
$$
F: E' \to E, x \mapsto [(\alpha, \phi_\alpha'(x))]
$$
where $\phi_\alpha'(x)$ is any local trivialization of the bundle $E'$ at $x$. We need to verify that $F$ is well-defined. That is, if there are two local trivializations $\phi_\alpha'$ and $\phi_\beta'$ on $\pi'(x) \in U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$, we need to show that $[(\alpha, \phi_\alpha'(x))] = [(\beta, \phi_\beta'(x))]$. Let $\phi_\alpha'(x) = (y, v)$. By the definition of the bundle $E'$, the transition function on $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$ is $\psi_{\alpha\beta}$, so we have $\phi_\beta' \circ \phi_\alpha'^{-1}(y, v) = (y, \psi_{\beta\alpha}(y)v)$. Thus:
\begin{align*}
[(\alpha, \phi_\alpha(x))] &= [(\alpha, y, v)] = [(\beta, y, \psi_{\beta\alpha}(y)v)] \\
&= [(\beta, \phi_\beta' \circ \phi_\alpha'^{-1}(y, v))] = [(\beta, \phi_\beta' \circ \phi_\alpha'^{-1} \circ \phi_\alpha (x))] = [(\beta, \phi_\beta'(x))]
\end{align*}
Hence, $F$ is well-defined and does not depend on the choice of local trivialization. At the same time, we have
$$
\pi \circ F (x) = \pi[(\alpha, \phi_\alpha'(x))] = \pi_1 \circ \phi_\alpha'(x) = \pi'(x)
$$
where $\pi_1$ is the projection onto the first component, and the last equality follows from the definition of the bundle's commutative diagram. This means we have $\pi \circ F = \pi'$, more precisely, $\pi \circ F = id_B \circ \pi'$. On the other hand, for a fixed $b \in U_\alpha \subseteq B$, the map $F \big|_{\pi'^{-1}(b)}: \pi'^{-1}(b) \to \pi^{-1}(b)$ is linear: $\forall x, y \in \pi'^{-1}(b), \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$:
\begin{align*}
F \big|_{\pi'^{-1}(b)}: \lambda x + y &\mapsto [(\alpha, \phi_\alpha' \big|_{\pi'^{-1}(b)}(\lambda x + y))] \\
&= [(\alpha, \lambda \phi_\alpha' \big|_{\pi'^{-1}(b)}(x) + \phi_\alpha' \big|_{\pi'^{-1}(b)}(y))] \\
&= \lambda [(\alpha, \phi_\alpha' \big|_{\pi'^{-1}(b)}(x))] + [(\alpha, \phi_\alpha' \big|_{\pi'^{-1}(b)}(y))]
\end{align*}
where the first equality is due to the linearity of the local trivialization $\phi_\alpha' \big|_{\pi'^{-1}(b)}$ (required by definition), and the second equality is due to the addition operation in the vector space $\pi^{-1}(b)$ (defined earlier). Hence, we see that $F \big|_{\pi'^{-1}(b)}$ is a linear map between vector spaces. Thus, by definition, we know that $(F, id)$ is a bundle homomorphism. Next, we need to prove that it is also a bundle isomorphism. To this end, we consider the kernel of the linear map $F \big|_{\pi'^{-1}(b)}$. $\forall x \in \text{Ker} F \big|_{\pi'^{-1}(b)}$, we have $[(\alpha, \phi_{\alpha}' \big|_{\pi'^{-1}(b)})] = 0$, i.e., $\pi_2 \circ \phi_\alpha' \big|_{\pi'^{-1}(b)}(x) = 0$. By definition, $\phi_\alpha'$ as a local trivialization is a linear isomorphism between $\pi'^{-1}(b) \cong \{b\} \times \mathbb{R}^n$. Therefore, if $\pi_2 \circ \phi_\alpha' \big|_{\pi'^{-1}(b)}(x) = 0$, then $x = 0$. Hence, $\text{Ker} F \big|_{\pi'^{-1}(b)} = 0$, so $F \big|_{\pi'^{-1}(b)}$ is surjective. Since $\pi'^{-1}(b)$ is $n$-dimensional, $F \big|_{\pi'^{-1}(b)}$ is a linear isomorphism.
